# Масштабирование некорректно работает при использовании flexbox и angular-gridster

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Возникла проблема при масштабировании страницы средствами браузера (например, для `Iceweasel/Firefox`, `Chrome/Chromium` по сочетаниям клавиш: `"Ctrl" + "-", "Ctrl" + "+", "Ctrl" + "0"`, либо через меню браузера) при использовании `flexbox`. Масштабируется все, кроме блока `panel-content`.

Также используются AngularJS, [angular-gridster.js](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster), Bootstrap 3.

Код:

```
<div ng-app="someApp" ng-controller="someCtrl" style="background-color: red; width: 100%;">
    <div gridster="gridsterOpts">
        <ul>
            <li class="" gridster-item="block" ng-repeat="block in sorted_blocks">
                <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: blue;">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: green;">{{ block.title }}</div>
                    <div class="panel-content image-responsive"  style="background-color: yellow;"
                         ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + block.image + ')'}"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Контроллер:

```
angular.module('someApp', ['gridster']).controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.gridsterOpts = {
        resizable: {
            enabled: false
        },
        columns: 10
    };
    $scope.sorted_blocks = [{
        id: 1,
        sizeX: 3,
        sizeY: 3,
        image: 'http://i.imgur.com/NI1Xm16.jpg',
        title: 'название1',
        row: 0,
        col: 3
    }, {
        id: 2,
        sizeX: 3,
        sizeY: 3,
        image: 'http://i.imgur.com/x6qmeUY.jpg',
        title: 'название2',
        row: 0,
        col: 0
    }];
});
```

Стили

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.panel .panel-content {    
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-responsive {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Код на JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/9/
Для наглядности выделил разными цветами блоки.

Во всех примерах, например, здесь http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/ с масштабированием проблем нет, однако там используется чистый `flexbox`.

При использовании `angular-gridster.js` без `flexbox` также с масштабированием проблем нет, [официальный пример](https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/main)

Если я убираю вот этот стиль

```
.panel .panel-content {    
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

тогда блок `panel-content` (желтый) соответственно скрывается, т.к. в нем нет контента. Блок `panel` (синий) остается того же размера, однако масштабирования по-прежнему не происходит, из чего можно сделать выводы, что проблема именно в блоке `panel`.

Обновление:
Если убрать стили flexbox http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/10/ (изображение, конечно, пропадает), то масштабирование все равно не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо было добавить еще один внешний контейнер, в данном случае `div`, с фиксированной шириной, тогда масштабирование отрабатывает корректно
http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/11/